# Generic for an object with an unknown number of string properties

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript generic for an object with an unknown number of string parameters as such:

```js
type Params<T extends string[]> = Record<T[number], string>;
```

but if I want to use it I have to write an array every time as such

```js
const params: Params<['param1', 'param2', ...]> = { param1: etc...
```

Is there a way to define this generic without using an array, so I can use it as:

```js
const params: Params<'param1', 'param2', ...> = { param1: etc...
```

Comment: Why not `Params<"param1" | "param2" | ...>`? Then `T extends string`, `Record<T, string>` - https://tsplay.dev/Nn506w.

Comment: because it's not an `OR` case. If the prop is there it's going to be in the object.

Comment: ...maybe you should actually try that.

Comment: If you're writing `Params[number]` then you're already turning it into an "OR case" (conventionally called a union).  If you think there's a problem with `"param1" | "param2" | ...` then please demonstrate it as a [mre]; otherwise you should consider accepting such an answer.

Comment: But that's what not an OR, it's a union. And `Record<"a" | "b", string>` means the object should have two keys - `a` and `b`: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPAErhIzAA8ARFFfAD7xUBGVANPJjAJYoDmAPgDcAWABQ43EgB0UIfAD0CgPIBpSXmnN5StRplgdCkDBhlxQA)

Comment: Also see what `Param[number]` would be in your case: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDaAiAhhgNDDAIzwOAwF0YsIZRIoBuAWACgoBPABwFMYAFLACcsAWxqoOPEHHiJmLAPQKYKgHoB+VpN4AlbqEEATANLd24-kNEQ0YAK4jC3QeXlKVMDUA)

Comment: I would go that route as a last resort but I would still prefer to know if there was a way to do it without actually writing the '|' or the array

Comment: `type Params<T extends string[]> = Record<Params[number], string>;` actually gives error about circular reference (probably you meant `T[number]`)

Comment: "I would still prefer to know if there was a way to do it without actually writing the '|' or the array" Could you articulate why `|` is bad but `,` would be good?  The former has the advantage of being possible and doing exactly the same thing as `T[number]`, while the latter is impossible.  TypeScript does not have variadic generic types.  The answer to your question is "no, that's not possible, you should use a union".  Can you articulate why it would be a "last resort" to do the conventional thing that works?

Answer (score 0):

Since one good solution was already suggested in the comments, here's another one I thought of, just for fun:

```
type SplitStr<T extends string> = 
    T extends `${infer R}, ${infer F}`
        ? R | SplitStr<F>
        : T

type Params<T extends string> = Record<SplitStr<T>, string>;

const params1: Params<'param1, param2'> = { param1: '123' }
// error, param2 is missing

const params2: Params<'param1, param2'> = { param1: '123', param2: '678' }
// ok
```